# How to Validate a SOAP Payload Request XML and SOAP Response XML against WSDL using .Net core 3.1?

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core, wsdl, xsd-validation

I am receiving the SOAP Request XML which need to be validated against the WSDL.
Also, SOAP Response XML should be validated against the WSDL using the **.Net core 3.1** version

Comment: The xml should always be validated with a schema where the xml is generated.  Not to ship data to clients that has not be validated.  Do the xml have any references to a schema?

Comment: Yes, Request and Response XML have a reference to a schema. Because Request and Response XML contains the **parameters** and **Datatype** and **schemaLocation** etc.

Comment: So you want to validate the request/response xml against the schema.  Do you also need to validate against the WSDL?

Comment: Need to validate against with WSDL

Comment: Then you need a WSDL schema.

Comment: Yes, I do have a WSDL schema in file at the client system.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.validate?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @jdweng above you mentioned document helped. Thank You!